# Панель разделов

Tags: 1с

После обновления *1С* список открывается не весь, а прокрутить вниз нет возможности.

Как настроить программу так, чтобы был доступ к тем строкам, что скрыты внизу?

На картинке, например после раздела "см.также" идет список, который виден не полностью.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Версию платформы уточните.
Но вообще никак это не настраивается.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать вам сделать данную настройку, которая выводит все строки в левой части экрана: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]